# Convert string to a valid MS SQL datetime to use for search in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I saw a lot of answers, most of which include using of `DateTime.ParseExact` and "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but it's not working for me and I'm not sure that those answers are 100% related to the problem I need to solve.

I have table with records from the database. The use can perform search based on different criteria one of which is date. I use some inherited jQuery calendar and in my controller the data from the date filed comes in format `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`. I want to be able to use this information to perform search in the database for records on the same date. The one problem is that I want to use only the date but not the time, but I'm not sure in what order to solve this problem so I decided to convert the incoming string to valid MS SQL datetime and see what happen and the to think about the time.

I tried different things, this is my last after which I decide to post here :

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selDate))
    {
        CultureInfo myCItrad = new CultureInfo("bg-BG", false);
        DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
           selDate,
           "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss",
           myCItrad);
        model = model.Where(m => m.Date == parsedDate);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `model = model.Where(m => m.Date.Date == parsedDate.Date);` ?

Comment: Just did, the same mistake I get all the time - `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: Can you please post a sample string with a date?

Comment: This is `.ToString()` date directly from the database - `8.5.2013 г. 15:43:40 ч.`. And this is what I get in my controller and try to parse - `"23/05/2013 09:04:45"`

Comment: It seems `DateTime.ParseExact` cannot parse `г` and `ч` characters. You should remove them or use another way to get the date in a proper format

Comment: Well this is the point - when I get the data from database and show it in my GUI, there is `г` and `ч` which made me include this - `CultureInfo myCItrad = new CultureInfo("bg-BG", false);`. But when the user pick a date I use jQuery calendar and it doesn't return those symbols so when I parse selDate the string doesn't contain them, it's - `"23/05/2013 09:04:45"`, no letters at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I parse selDate the string doesn't contain them, it's - "23/05/2013 09:04:45"

If your input string looks like `"23/05/2013 09:04:45"` then you should use this pattern for `ParseExact`: `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selDate))
{
    CultureInfo myCItrad = new CultureInfo("bg-BG", false);
    DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
       selDate,
       "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
       myCItrad);
    model = model.Where(m => m.Date == parsedDate);
}
```

Comment: Phew! Finally. It didn't worked with the specific culture but setting it back to `InvariantCulture` and simply with `m => m.Date` the magic is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Leron,

Date issues between application and SQL are well known.

1. SQL  and .NET date time types are different:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx
2. On both SQL and .NET there are numerous date time formats, all need to be treated as numbers types.

So, you need to know how to convert numerous date time formats on .NET side, to convert it to SQL type, and vice versa. Not a good practice...

1. Use SqlDateTime to conduct conversion. 
   Or:
2. A simple, a bit "dirty" solution, is something like that:

   - Take the date wanted by user. Calculate how many days is it from
     current (e.g. --> int days = (DateTime.Now-selectDate).Days;
   - Now on database query, do it using SQL: GetDate()-days

Answer (score 1):

> The one problem is that I want to use only the date but not the time,

This has nothing to do with SQL date formats.

If you want to use only the date and not the time, you could do something like:

```
model = model.Where(m => m.Date.Date == parsedDate.Date);
```

or if you prefer:

```
model = model.Where(m => (m.Date >= parsedDate.Date && m.Date < parsedDate.Date.AddDays(1));
```

In the above `m.Date.Date` and `parsedDate.Date` you are using the `DateTime.Date` property to get the date component of your date value, discarding the time component.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime in SQL is this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. correct code is

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(selDate, "yyyy-MM-dd" myCItrad);
```

Comment: I tried both - with my specific cultural info and invariant cultural info but got the same mistake with both.